# MYSQL Tag column redundancy

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a tag table like this:

```
TAG ID | TAG_NAME | IMAGE_ID 

ex: 
1 | FUNNY | 10 <br />
2 | DOG   | 10
3 | SUNNY | 10 
4 | JULY  | 10
```

and I also keep a reference to all the tags associated to an image in the image table

```
IMAGE_ID | IMAGE_NAME | IMAGE_TAGS ( varchar(255) utf8_general_ci )     

ex: 
10 | dog.jpg | FUNNY,DOG,SUNNY,JULY
```

The reasoning for the tag column in the images table, is so that if an image is retrieved, all the associated tags can be retrieved as well without having to dip into the tags table.. but for some reason I'm starting to think it would just be best to get all the associated tags from the tag table to reduce redundancy and to be certain it's associated with that tag (it could have been removed or deleted but the data doesn't match) - 
 but then again I also feel it might be benefical to keep the tags column.. I can't figure out if I should keep the column or drop it..  am I over thinking this?

Comment: Don't worry about 'dipping into the tags table'. `JOIN` statements are going to be a lot more efficient and load-friendly than storing the data twice in the long run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `image_tags` column should be removed.

When you store comma separated data, you will loose all the indexing and integrity goodness that comes with your database engine. This is why it's considered a sql anti-pattern.

Your tags table should probably not have the `image_id` column either. Consider using this schema:

```
tags
---
tag_id *
tag_name

images
---
image_id *
image_name 

imagetags
----
it_image_id *
it_tag_id *
```

The tags for each image are kept in a m:n table `imagetags`. Foreign key constraints will help to further strengthen the data integrity.

Comment: "Your tags table should probably not have the image_id column either."  but this is how I associate images with tags

Comment: I like this n:n model better.

Comment: Oh i see, I should have 2 tables for tags.. tags with Tag_id | tag_name and  tag table with Image_id | tag_id

Comment: @bushdiver I don't believe that's what Jack is saying. His model uses a mapping table.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused on the third table.. imagetags: it_image_id * it_tag_id *  <--- These two match tag_id  and image_id  from the first 2 tables right?

Comment: @njk Maybe the OP just goes by the table names (which both have 'tags') in them :)

Comment: @bushdiver Yes, that's right. Tags can have multiple images and images can have multiple tags.

Comment: I'm reading more about avoiding comma-separated values in sql database, I use comma-seperated values all over my database.. thank you this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-design your tags table. A relational database form calls for each column to only have a single value. This means that you should only have a single tag in each column. Relational databases are made to be this way; to efficiently `JOIN` your tags `ON` your images.

```
> image
id | image_name
1          dog.jpg

> image_tag
image_id | tag
1          funny
1          dog
1          sunny
```

You don't need a surrogate key for the tags as you would have a primary composite key (`image_id, tag`) in your `image_tag` table.

Comment: You also have a surrogate key for your tags. This is not needed as it removes uniqueness for your tags.